# How do I add intervals of days using month number from database?

Tags: php

I'm trying to get it to work with the database variable called $endmonth which contains various of Month numbers but nothing doesn't display.

So for example if I was to change $endmonth variable in the first parameter to 5 the program will add 40 days which displays 07-02 which is July the 2nd but how can I do this with various month numbers from the database.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
{
    $endMonth = $row['month_number'];
        
    $current_month = DateTime::createFromFormat('m', $endMonth );
    date_add($current_month,date_interval_create_from_date_string("40 days"));
    print_r(date_format($current_month,"m-d"));

}
```

How do I loop through that variable from the database for the program to add intervals of days from month number which is coming from the database using PHP functions not MySQL query?
Because it currently works when assigning a number to the parameter.

Comment: what is the value of $endMonth?

Comment: What's the problem with the current code? Can you supply some sample data and expected results of your program?

Comment: DateTime::createFromFormat('m', $endMonth ); -> this syntax will not work for month number !

Comment: @El_Vanja Ok in the database I have got column called  month_number which contains whole number such as 3, 2,4,2,1,5 which is similar to March,Feburary,April,Feburary,January and May
when adding 40days to those number you will get 4,3,5,3,2,6 as expected results

Comment: Does anyone know how to calculate dates from database?

Comment: You seem to be expecting those 40 days to be added to the first day of the month. If that is so, then create the first day of the month explicitly. When you do it like this (not specifying the day) it takes the current one.